# linked-list in C++ how to go to "next element" using STL list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a very basic question. I want to use STL's list instead of creating my own linked-list ( my code is shown below)

```
struct myList
{

    myList *next;
    myList *previous;
};

myList->next = NULL;
```

Using STL list:

```
#include <list>

std::list<int> L;
L.push_back(1);
```

My question is, how to access the "next" element in STL's list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::list` is a container. To access individual nodes, you need to use an iterator.

For example, to get the head node, you use

```
std::list<int>::const_iterator cit = L.begin();
```

To move to the next node, you use

```
++ cit;
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [std::advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/):

```
std::list<int> mylist;
...
int index = 5;
std::list<int>::iterator ith_iterator = mylist.begin();
std::advance(ith_iterator, index);
int& ith_element = *ith_iterator;
```

Answer (score 1):

use an **iterator**:

```
std::list<int>::iterator i = L.begin();
std::list<int>::iterator i_end = L.end();
while(i!=i_end)
   {
   ++i;
   }
```

Comment: Yeap, ++ i was the key.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As of C++11 you could use std::next() provided by the iterator library

```
#include <iterator>
#include <list>

std::list<int> L;
L.push_back(1);
L.push_back(2);

auto it = L.begin();
std::cout << *it << *(std::next(it,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the next element then use can use iterator and advance(it,position);
So it will only access the second/next element

```
list<int> myList{10, 20, 30};
list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin();
// position is calculated from the beginning of the list
advance(it,1);

cout<<*it;
```

So this will directly print the next element and if you want you can print the previous element `advance(it,-1)`  or next to next `advance(it,2)`
I hope this answers your question but if you still have any doubt just ping me
I am always ready to help!!